# ErrorException Undefined Variable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

Hey guys I just started learning how to use Laravel and when I tried running the code below I get:

> Undefined variable error

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($tasks as $task)
            <li>{{ $task->Todo }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code used in the `web.php` file:

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/tasks', function () {
        $tasks = DB::table('tasks')->get();
    //return $tasks;
        return view('welcome',compact($tasks));
    });
```

I discovered that if I use the `$GLOBALS['variable'];` to replace the `$tasks` variable in both files it works.

But in the example video from laracasts they didn't make use of the `$GLOBALS['variable'];`

This is the error I get:

> "Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\Users\Friday\Documents\Documentations\laraprojects\BrainGear\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the variable name in the `compact()` helper (as @utdev said). You can read more about this [here](http://php.net/compact). So:

```
return view('welcome', compact('tasks'));
```

Another option is to send the variable to the view like this:

```
return view('welcome')->with('tasks', $tasks);
```

or even "sugared" (equivalent to the last one):

```
return view('welcome')->withTasks($tasks);
```

To know more about this, check the [Passing data to views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views) section of the documentation.

Comment: thanks a ton for both the editing and the answering.  i felt real goofy. just recognized that i used `$tasks` instead of `'tasks'`

Comment: @TheGripVic actually the normal behaviour would be to assume what you did, but every method has its peculiarities. Btw, A year and a half ago I was also just beginning with Laravel, now I know a little bit more -after a lot of mistakes, research, Laracasts and StackOverflow- So I can return the help received and I'm also to still learning. We are all here to improve, my friend. Have a good day.

Comment: @HCK nice copy pasting

Comment: Mate, I quoted your answer and added additional information (like docs) and also alternatives to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the variable like this:

```
    return view('welcome', compact('tasks'));
```

Then you can use it like you did but use lowercase for that case please:

```
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <li>{{ $task->todo }}</li>
    @endforeach
```